# How to rotate 45% arrow icon using CSS

Tags: html, css

Here what I need to do is rotate 45% using below CSS tricks.

Here I  have included what I have tried,

```css
.hero {  
 position:relative;

}


.hero:after,
.hero:after {
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
    top: 98.1%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly are "blow css tricks"?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 .hero {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
   -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=5); /*for IE*/
  }
```

```css
.hero {  
    position:relative;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
   -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=5); /*for IE*/
}
.hero:after,
.hero:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 98.1%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}

.hero{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use transform property

```
.hero {
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer but this is not working in IE8 if any css tricks for this.

Answer (score 0):

trying this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/4je79/)**

**css**

```
.rotate-45-left:before {
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.rotate-45-right:before {
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **transform:rotate(45deg);**

```css
.hero {  
 position:relative;

}


.hero:after,
.hero:after {
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
    top: 98.1%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}

.hero{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
.hero {
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the border styles to

`border-left: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-top: solid 50px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;`

```css
.hero {  
 position:relative;

}


.hero:after,
.hero:after {
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
    top: 98.1%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-top: solid 50px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```